# sbt running but can't see on port 9000 centos 6.5

Tags: rpm

After downloading the sbt.rpm (version 0.13.1) and installing with yum it appears to be running successfully but when I go to http://mysite.com:9000 it's not found.

Here is some of the output after command `sbt`

```
   ent/0.13.1/jars/test-agent.jar ...
   [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.1!test-agent.jar (1248ms)
   downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/test-        interface/1.0/test-interface-1.0.jar ...
   [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0!test-interface.jar    (864ms)
downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-    sbt/apply-macro/0.13.1/jars/apply-macro.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.1!apply-macro.jar     (1946ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
   confs: [default]
   43 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (12646kB/207ms)
   Getting Scala 2.10.3 (for sbt)...
    downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/jline/2.10.3/jline-     2.10.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.3!jline.jar (1180ms)
downloading     http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.4/jansi-1.4.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4!jansi.jar (1316ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24447kB/136ms)
[info] Set current project to local (in build file:/usr/local/)
  >
```

Then command `run` and I get the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

I am attempting to get this running so I can play a scala language backgammon game.

Getting a little further along I have placed wbillingsley/play-backgammon scala folder into /usr/local/src/main/scala  and now when I do run command I get the following:

```
    Loading /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
 [info] Set current project to local (in build file:/usr/local/)
 > run
 [info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to /usr/local/target/scala-2.10/classes...
 [error] /usr/local/src/main/scala/play-    backgammon/app/controllers/Application.scala:3: not found: object play
 [error] import play.api._
 [error]        ^
[error] /usr/local/src/main/scala/play-   backgammon/app/controllers/Application.scala:5: not found: object play
[error] import play.api.mvc._
[error]        ^
[error] /usr/local/src/main/scala/play-   backgammon/app/controllers/Application.scala:8: not found: object play
 [error] import play.api.libs.json._
 [error]        ^
```

Comment: If you point me to the rbt.rpm file you used I can try this out and see if I can offer some assistance.

Comment: @slm That is unbelievably helpful and kind spirited of you! Thanks.I am very interested to see what you discover. The rpm is from http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html RPM and the scala game created by Dr William Billingsley is from https://github.com/wbillingsley/play-backgammon/blob/master/README.md%22%3Ehere%3C/a%3E

Comment: http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.1/sbt.rpm

Comment: See A. Got the game working. It was slow to compile it but one it came up it was perfectly playable. Re-running it was fast afterwards.

Comment: Incredible, I didn't actually believe it would work because no releases on the other hand the guy that created it is an Honorary Lecturer in Computer Science and it took him a WHOLE YEAR to put this together. He is in Australia and I have already written to him to tell him if I get it working how much I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps I used to get this working. I'll note that I only used the 2 URLs that you provided:

- [Setup](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html)
- [github repo - wbillingsley / play-backgammon](https://github.com/wbillingsley/play-backgammon)

#### Step #1 - install SBT

I ran the following 2 commands to download and install SBT.

```
$ wget http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.1/sbt.rpm 
$ sudo yum localinstall sbt.rpm
```

#### Step #2 - Clone GIT repo

Next I ran this command to clone a copy of the GitHub repo for the backgammon game.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/wbillingsley/play-backgammon.git
```

#### Step #3 - Compiling backgammon

Probably the critical step you're omitting is that you have to change directories into the backgammon game, prior to running SBT.

```
$ cd play-backgammon
```

Now from within the project directory, run `sbt`.

```
$ sbt
Loading /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.12.1 ...
downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.1/jars/sbt.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.1!sbt.jar (697ms)
downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.12.1/jars/main.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.12.1!main.jar (2133ms)
...
Getting Scala 2.9.2 (for sbt)...
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.9.2/scala-compiler-2.9.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.9.2!scala-compiler.jar (6836ms)
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9.2/scala-library-2.9.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.2!scala-library.jar (4865ms)
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/jline/2.9.2/jline-2.9.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.9.2!jline.jar (388ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    4 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (20090kB/71ms)
[info] Loading project definition from /home/saml/programming_projects/scala/play-backgammon/project
[info] Set current project to play-backgammon (in build file:/home/saml/programming_projects/scala/play-backgammon/)
[play-backgammon] $
```

#### Step #4 - Running the game

```
[play-backgammon] $ run

Getting Scala 2.10.0-RC1 ...
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.0-RC1/scala-compiler-2.10.0-RC1.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.0-RC1!scala-compiler.jar (9087ms)
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0-RC1/scala-library-2.10.0-RC1.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0-RC1!scala-library.jar (3653ms)
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.0-RC1/scala-reflect-2.10.0-RC1.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.0-RC1!scala-reflect.jar (2091ms)
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/jline/2.10.0-RC1/jline-2.10.0-RC1.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.0-RC1!jline.jar (479ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
...
...
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/w3c/css/sac/1.3/sac-1.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.w3c.css#sac;1.3!sac.jar (372ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/netty/netty/3.2.7.Final/netty-3.2.7.Final.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.jboss.netty#netty;3.2.7.Final!netty.jar(bundle) (656ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/easytesting/fest-util/1.1.6/fest-util-1.1.6.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.easytesting#fest-util;1.1.6!fest-util.jar (331ms)
[info] Done updating.
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

#### Step #5 - PLAY!

Once you're to this point you can then fire up your web browser and access the game via the URL `http://localhost:9000`.

[image: ss of game]

Comment: I have been gone all day and won't be able to follow this until tomorrow but have to laugh because probably all my problems with installing ffmpeg and other things has had to do with directories.Thank you for helping me out so much. I am also laughing because I am impressed with the apparent ease you have done this!

Comment: @cea - an ex-coworker of mine and a very good friend is the author/maintainer of SBT so I'm somewhat familiar w/ Scala 8-)

Comment: I wish I had some people in real life that share my passion for computers but there is not one which means harder to learn. Btw you were right about starting in game folder, it all works :) Is there a way to embed it in a page, I mean embed that url it gives in a block I wonder. Otherwise if I ask a friend to play , they'll invariably say play what? and I will have to tell them to click on link and they'll have some excuse why they cannot click a link.

Comment: @cea - you could just email them the link. When I accessed the top level URL (localhost:9000) should be able to be wrapped into Nginx or Apache reverse proxying that URL so that it's exposed and accessible from outside your LAN.

Comment: got a reply from the creator :) "Actually, if I change the code a bit it should be possible to embed it in the drupal site, and just connect to a server.  It’ll require a few changes on the server side so that the browser will be willing to work with JSON data coming from a different server than the drupal page though. (I’ll need to set CORS headers in the HTTP responses, and add a controller method to support HTTP OPTIONS requests. It’d also need a different way of letting the second player put in the game id, other than generating a unique link for them.)"